# Three.js use variable to set HSL background color

Tags: three.js, hsl

I am trying to set the renderer.setClearColor() to a new HSL color using a variable. It works if I define the variable directly, but when I try to change it by using another variable, I get this error:

```
THREE.Color: Unknown color hsl(color1[0], 96%, 95%)
```

here is the code I am using to try and just change the hue:

```
backgroundColor = new THREE.Color("hsl(0, 96%, 95%)");

function getColors(){
color1 = [];
color1h = (data[1] / 359);
color1s = (0.90);
color1l = (0.65);
color1.push(color1h, color1s, color1l);
backgroundColor = new THREE.Color("hsl(color1[0], 96%, 95%)");
}
...
renderer.setClearColor(backgroundColor);
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the actual bug in the OP's code is that it's passing a variable as a string. Using template literal it should be:

```
backgroundColor = new THREE.Color(`hsl(${color1[0]}%, 96%, 95%)`);
```

---

I had this same issue, but it was caused by the hsl values being floats instead of integers. In other words I was passing something like `hsl(45.356456%, 96%, 95%)`. I was able to fix it by just rounding the number to the nearest integer.

```
backgroundColor = new THREE.Color(`hsl(${Math.round(color1[0])}%, 96%, 95%)`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to set and change the background color using HSL parameters:

```
var color = new THREE.Color(); // create once and reuse it
```

Then, to set or change the clear color

```
color.setHSL( 0.5, 0.90, 0.95 );
renderer.setClearColor( color );
```

---

There is also another pattern that is supported:

```
scene.background = new THREE.Color().setHSL( 0.5, 0.90, 0.95 );
```

And to change it:

```
scene.background.setHSL( 0.9, 0.90, 0.95 );
```

three.js r.92